# What is the "secret key" used in the JWT example in the RFC?

Tags: hmac, sha256, jwt

I have been reading the `JWT RFC`, and in [section 3.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token-19#section-3.1) they give an example `JWT` along with the MAC.

I was wondering if: is it known what is the value of the secret key that they used with SHA-256 to generate the example in `RFC`?

I want to use the example in a test case so I'd like to reproduce it exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the key is given in [Appendix 1.1 of the draft for "JSON Web Signature (JWS)"](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-jose-json-web-signature-25#appendix-A.1.1) in the [JSON Web Key format](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-jose-json-web-key-25) as:

```
{
    "kty":"oct",
    "k":"AyM1SysPpbyDfgZld3umj1qzKObwVMkoqQ-EstJQLr_T-1qS0gZH75aKtMN3Yj0iPS4hcgUuTwjAzZr1Z9CAow"
}
```

I misunderstood that the two links named "Appendix A.1" at the end of the "JWT Example" section actually go to different locations. Tha passage with the links is reproduced below:

---

*This computation is illustrated in more detail in [Appendix A.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token-19#appendix-A.1) of [[JWS](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token-19#ref-JWS)].  See [Appendix A.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token-19#appendix-A.1) for an example of an encrypted JWT.*